# Make click go through an element to one behind it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div that spans my entire page with some buttons. The div however, is transparent. I have placed a video behind the div, that I would like to be able to start and stop. Of course, only when I press somewhere that isn't a button. But currently, the div is consuming the click. I would like the click to propagate to the element behind it. However, I would still like it to block swipes.

**CSS**

```css
.root {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.7fr 1fr 0.7fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas: "left center right";
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div
   className="root"
   style={{
      display: "grid"
      width: `calc(100% - ${arg1? arg3: 0}px)`,
      height: `calc(100% - ${arg2 ? arg4: 0}px)`,
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff00",
   }}
   onClick={(ev) => {
      console.log("cl");
   }}
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `pointer-events: none;` css property.

Comment: Is there also a way to disable swipes going through, and only letting click through?

Comment: Not exactly, try adding the event handlers to a parent element that contains everything.